# Return Global Variable from Javascript Method

Tags: javascript, function, methods, web

I have a method:

```
function calculateThings(newdata){


}
```

How do I return a global variable from within it?

Thanks!

Sorry for the lack of detail.

```
var thisData = "";

function calculateThings(newData) {

    thisData = newData.things.otherthings //has a value of 10;

}

alert(thisData) //returns nothing
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a problem with `return window.myGlobalVar;` ?

Comment: if the variable is global why you should return it inside a function? Just read its value after function call

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan It doesn't matter, if they manipulate it and want it immediately, why not return it?

Comment: @ianpgall, I don't see the usefullness in returning a global variable. So Why not simply read the value after function call? This is just curiosity for the question

Comment: I have a feeling that the real question is "how do I work with a global variable that has been shadowed by a function parameter".

Comment: Or maybe the he's making an XHR request, and is wondering why the returned value doesn't show the response, and assumed that using a global is the solution. This question has a serious lack of detail.

Comment: graystateiscoming, I agree. @Reg, could you explain further providing an example fiddle of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I really don't see the usefulness in arguing about returning a global variable. If someone is looking to return one, let them! Maybe it's easier to organize, like: `if (calculateThings("asdf") == true) { }` is much easier than having to call `calculateThings` and then check a global variable. Maybe the code that is calling `calculateThings` has no idea about the global variable and the global variable's meaning is to simply store a state or something. All the calling code wants to know is if the global variable is true or false (or whatever value)

Comment: @ianpgall, my need to argue on subject is necessary if I want to try to give a useful answer to OP on a question so poorly described and without a clue of what OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan You're just arguing about WHY someone would want to return a global variable, which has no significance... If you were arguing about HOW to do it, maybe it would help...

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: Yep, more info was needed. Looks like he posted a dupe instead of improving this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427059/variable-not-being-set

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be much point in returning a global variable, the function can just set it and other functions reference it.

```
var setGlobal = (function(global) {
  return function(value) {
    global.someVarName = value;
  }
}(this));

var readGlobal = (function(global) {
  return function() {
    return global.someVarName;
  }
}(this));

setGlobal('foo');
alert(readGlobal()); // foo
alert(someVarName);  // foo
```