# Variable not being set

Tags: javascript, function, methods, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return Global Variable from Javascript Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426135/return-global-variable-from-javascript-method)

I have this.

```
var thisData = "";
function calculateThings(newData) {
     thisData = newData.things.otherthings //has a value of 10;
}
alert(thisData) //returns nothing
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It appears as though this question is the same issue you asked about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426135/return-global-variable-from-javascript-method Why make a new question instead of responding to those who were asking you for feedback?

Answer (score 1):

you need to call your function:

`calculateThings(newData);`

should be more like:

```
 var thisData = "";
 function calculateThings(data) {
      thisData = data.things.otherthings //has a value of 10;
 }
 calculateThings(newData);
 alert(thisData) //returns nothing
```

where data is your parameter, and you can pass whatever you want into it.

Answer (score 0):

You created a function but never call it. You need to call it via:

```
var thisData = "";
function calculateThings(newData) {
     thisData = newData.things.otherthings //has a value of 10;
}
alert(calculateThings(thisData));
```

or you can self-invoke the function like:

```
(function calculateThings(newData) {
     thisData = newData.things.otherthings //has a value of 10;
})()
```